# Cocoa : Detect changes to any form element

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I have a form built in interface builder.

Now I want to receive a notification when **any element that is a child of a particular view is changed** (be it text, or the select element, or a checkbox, etc).

Basically I want to know whether or not the form is "dirty" (changed).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Notification of changes to a view is pretty different from a "dirty" bit for the form.  One is interface event detection and the other has to do with data storage.  Are you using persistent storage?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about (persistent storage). Basically I want to update my model when the user clicks on another row from a table view or when the window is closed.

Comment: Sorry, not knowing much about your setup I thought I'd start by narrowing down the options.  Are you using CoreData?

Comment: @RishiG - at the moment it's just all in memory - no data storage yet. But it will most likely be coming from a plist.

Comment: Sorry for the runaround.  I guess I had a more complicated data entry process in mind.  I think my answer below is probably more of what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple answer is to connect those UI elements which might change the value of the data model to an IBAction in the parent view controller.  In that IBAction you can decide if you want to save the data, present a dialog, etc.